# What does mmap do?

Tags: c, mmap

What does this line of code do?

```
mmap(NULL, n, PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
```

Answer (score 18):

It requests a private, writeable anonymous mapping of `n` bytes of memory.

- A private mapping means it's not shared with other processes (eg, after a `fork()` the child and parent will have independent mappings);
- An anonymous mapping means that it's not backed by a file.

In this case, it is essentially requesting a block of `n` bytes of memory, so roughly equivalent to `malloc(n)` (although it must be freed with `munmap()` rather than `free()`, and it will be page-aligned).  It's also requesting that the memory be writeable but not requesting that it be readable, however writeable and unreadable memory is typically not a combination supported by the underlying hardware. When `PROT_WRITE` alone is requested, POSIX allows the implementation to supply memory that can also be read and/or executable.

Comment: On x86 PROT_WRITE implies PROT_READ and POSIX allows this.

Answer (score 12):

`man mmap` will help you here.

It creates a memory mapping in the virtual address space of the process. It's creating an *anonymous* mapping, which is rather like using `malloc` to allocate `n` bytes of memory.

The parameters are:

- `NULL` - the kernel will choose an address for the mapping
- `n` - length of the mapping (in bytes)
- `PROT_WRITE` - pages may be written
- `MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE` - mapping is not backed by a file, and updates written to the mapping are private to the process
- `-1` - the file descriptor; not used because the mapping is not backed by a file
- `0` - offset within the file at which to start the mapping - again, not used, because the mapping is not backed by a file